# How to change Id of cloned row in below jQuery code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm trying to achieve the change of Id But the code what I have is only having the code to change the name of the element can anyone please help to change the id of the element in the below give jquery code

Thanks in Advance.
Html View-source code is as follows

```
<div style="width:700px; padding:5px; background-color:white;">
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <a id="addNew" href="#">+</a> <a id="remove" href="#">-</a>
            <table id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>UserName</th>
                        <th>Password</th>
                        <th>Service line</th>
                        <th>Track</th>
                        <th>subtrack</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="TemplateRow" style="border:1px solid black">
                        <td><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Username field is required." id="z0__UserName" name="[0].UserName" type="text" value="Required" /></td>
                        <td><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="z0__Password" name="[0].Password" type="text" value="Required" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="wrapper-dropdown Service_Line" id="z0__Service_Line" name="[0].Service_Line">
                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                <option value="A">A</option>
                                <option value="B">B</option>
                                <option value="C">C</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="wrapper-dropdown Track" id="z0__Track" name="[0].Track">
                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                <option> </option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="wrapper-dropdown Sub_Track" id="z0__Sub_Track" name="[0].Sub_Track">
                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                <option> </option>
                            </select>
                        </td>

                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Save Bulk Data" />
            <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8Iv10IHEfBVKvKHuuUa1dyFaBzngVKjKG3-va_WAZxz30jKahHLoMeCFM1qbmA9nPf01CYch9VobgyZOOv60VPsPJjlD4yUbH4F7TF0QrcJJTnMpj88n1Et9Ksa2i2y23CBEPqICCPoC18cdrY1Ral0" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Jquery is as follows

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //1. Add new row
        $("#addNew").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $tableBody = $("#dataTable");
            var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
            var $trNew = $trLast.clone(true);
            var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
            $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
                // Replaced Name
                var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
                var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
                $(this).attr('name', newN);
                // If you have another Type then replace with default value
                $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");
            });
            $trLast.after($trNew);
        });
    });
```

I have tried by changing the attr(name) to attr(id) after changing like that its not changing the name but even not changing the ids too...

For more reference the Html code is as follows::

```
 <table id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>UserName</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Service line</th>
                <th>Track</th>
                <th>subtrack</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
             {
                int j = 0;
                foreach (var i in Model)
                {
                    <tr id="TemplateRow" style="border:1px solid black">
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].UserName)</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Password)</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (ViewBag.ServiceLineList != null)
                            {
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a[j].Service_Line, ViewBag.ServiceLineList as SelectList, "--Select--", new {  @class = "wrapper-dropdown Service_Line" })
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a[j].Track, new SelectList(" "), "--Select--", new {  @class = "wrapper-dropdown Track" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a[j].Sub_Track, new SelectList(" "), "--Select--", new { @class = "wrapper-dropdown Sub_Track" })
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @if (j > 0)
                            {
                                <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    j++;
                }
             }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Add your HTML code.

Comment: What id? You haven't shown us your HTML code so we don't know what id you need to change. Please edit your question with all of the relevant code so we can help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten in the present Jquery code no names are given in html but then also its changing the name of all cloned rows by adding sequential numbers in beginning so following the same format i want to change the id instead of name

Comment: @TigranAbrahamyan The Html code is also added please help

Comment: @FluffyKitten the html code is also added

Comment: So you are adding rows in your loop in the HTML code,*and* you are adding more in the jQuery? Will the ones added in the HTML have numbers in the id?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Yes adding rows by cloning them in jquery once they get cloned I want to change the id's not the names.
In the above code names are getting changed for all the elements  in var suffix line by instead i wanna change the id for all elements

Comment: Yes, but your HTML *also* has a loop that is adding rows. Will they have a number in their id, and if so, how is it getting added?

Comment: @FluffyKitten No they Don't

Comment: They should! The rows created the HTML loop shouldn't all have the same ID - ids are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Okay..Is their any way to change their id's as i only have first row and then i'm cloning them so they all are having same id's

Comment: So even though you have a loop in your HTML, you are only creating 1 row - the template row, is that correct?

Comment: yes @FluffyKitten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a unique id, we can keep a count of the rows added in the jQuery, and append this to the base name (e.g. `UserName`) to create a unique name and id. You say there will only be one row in the HTML, so we can start the count for our new rows at 1.

Every time the "Add New" button is clicked, the steps are (numbers match the comment numbers):

1. Initialise our variable to start the count
2. generate a unique id for the row, e.g. TemplateRow-1: `var newId = "TemplateRow-" + rowcount;`
3. Clone the row and pass in the id: `$trLast.clone(true).prop({ id: newId});`
4. generate the name and id for each input: get the input name, remove the `[n]` to get the base name (e.g. `UserName`), and use this to create the new name (e.g. `[1].UserName`) and id (e.g. `z1__UserName`).

**Working snippet:** I show the new id using console.log so you can see what is being added:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* 1. Initialise our variable to keep count of the rows added */
  var rowcount = 1;

  //Add new row
  $("#addNew").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $tableBody = $("#dataTable");
    var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");

    // 2. Create the new id with the row count
    var newId = "TemplateRow-" + rowcount;

    // 3. clone the row with our new id
    var $trNew = $trLast.clone(true).prop({ id: newId });

    // 4. rename each input and give an id
    $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function(i, val) {

      oldName = $(this).attr('name');
      inputParts = oldName.split(".");

      // set the  name and id with the base name and rowcount
      $(this).attr('name', '[' + rowcount + '].'+inputParts[1]);
      $(this).attr('id', 'z'+rowcount+'__'+inputParts[1]);

      $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");
    });
    
    $trLast.after($trNew);

    rowcount++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Service line</th>
            <th>Track</th>
            <th>subtrack</th>
            <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="TemplateRow" style="border:1px solid black">
<!--      <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
      <td><select name="serviceline"><option>1</option></select></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="track"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="subtrack"></td> -->
                        <td><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Username field is required." id="z0__UserName" name="[0].UserName" type="text" value="Required" /></td>
                        <td><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="z0__Password" name="[0].Password" type="text" value="Required" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="wrapper-dropdown Service_Line" id="z0__Service_Line" name="[0].Service_Line">
                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                <option value="A">A</option>
                                <option value="B">B</option>
                                <option value="C">C</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="wrapper-dropdown Track" id="z0__Track" name="[0].Track">
                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                <option> </option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="wrapper-dropdown Sub_Track" id="z0__Sub_Track" name="[0].Sub_Track">
                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                <option> </option>
                            </select>
                        </td>

                        <td></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="addNew">Add New</button>
```

Comment: i don't want to increment template row count instead i want to increment the id's of the elements in the table like username,password,service_Line,Track,Sub_track **TO**  username1 , password1 , service_Line1 , Track1 , Sub_track1
username2 , password2 , service_Line2 , Track2 , Sub_track2 and so on......

Comment: @Aakib Can you give us the HTML for the elements you want changed then? You haven't shown us the HTML for the inputs - only the script that generates them - so we have no idea what they are like to be able to work with them!

Comment: @Aakib I don't see the HTML code. I see your template script that generates the HTML but not the HTML itself. We need to see the actual HTML for the inputs.

Comment: @Aakib "View source" or In the browser's element inspector . I just need to see how one row of the inputs are structured.

Comment: @ FluffyKitten By adding the cloned rows or without them

Comment: @Aakib Without  - they are the ones that are correct, aren't they?

Comment: @ FluffyKitten Shall i paste the code in comments unable to paste whole code their it's getting cut
yes its correct

Comment: @Aakib No, edit your question to include it. Comments aren't designed for blocks of code

Comment: Unable to add source code the whole page is getting error if i edit the cod @FluffyKitten

Comment: @Aakib  I don't need all the source code, just the table row with the inputs

Comment: @Aakib OK, there you go! Your question sounded like it was just a unique id for the rows, which was ok. But needing unique names and ids for all the inputs too was a bit much for one question on Stack Overflow. It's all there though and every input is getting a unique id - everything is commented too in case you need to change anything to suit your own code. You owe me a drink after all that! :)

Comment: the id's in the view source code are auto generated as i haven't declared any id

Comment: @Aakib That was the problem! I was trying to match the auto-generated ids without seeing them :) Its working now - the ids and names have the same format as the first row, e.g. `z1__UserName`and  `[1].UserName`  so it should hopefully work.

Comment: Please help me @FluffyKitten only with the ids

Comment: @Aakib I don't understand... the code in the snippet makes the ids look like the first row but with a unique number. Is that not what you need?

Comment: Thankyou so much  bro Working f9 just need to remove z from dat fr me @FluffyKitten

Comment: @Aakib I'm not sure what you are asking, but you can change the id in this line: `$(this).attr('id', 'z'+rowcount+'__'+inputParts[1]);` - rowcount is the number and inputParts[1] is the name

Comment: i have a doubt can i ask u?

Comment: @Aakib Ok, whats up?

Comment: can u help me with dis same question little more help required https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63618991/how-to-increment-the-value-of-id-in-the-jquery