# How to pull the Incrementing id of the elements in the jquery

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The problem is when i try to pull the incrementing id's by using $("#[rowcount].Service_Line").change(function () {  as the rown count goes ++ for every loop it's not working can any one please help so that i can populate the dropdowns from the database
** if i have a set of rows with id's like [1].Service_Line,[2].Service_Line,[3].Service_Line,.......then how can i get them in jquery using $ symbol.**

Here is the code as follows of html from the view source

```
 <table id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>UserName</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Service line</th>
                <th>Track</th>
                <th>subtrack</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
             {
                int j = 0;
                foreach (var i in Model)
                {
                    <tr id="TemplateRow" style="border:1px solid black">
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].UserName)</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Password)</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (ViewBag.ServiceLineList != null)
                            {
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a[j].Service_Line, ViewBag.ServiceLineList as SelectList, "--Select--", new { @id = "Service_Line", @class = "wrapper-dropdown Service_Line" })
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a[j].Track, new SelectList(" "), "--Select--", new { @id="Track", @class = "wrapper-dropdown Track" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a[j].Sub_Track, new SelectList(" "), "--Select--", new { @class = "wrapper-dropdown Sub_Track" })
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @if (j > 0)
                            {
                                <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    j++;
                }
             }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The Jquery code is as follows

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    /* 1. Initialise our variable to keep count of the rows added */
    var rowcount = 1;

    //Add new row
    $("#addNew").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $tableBody = $("#dataTable");
        var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");

        // 2. Create the new id with the row count
        var newId = "TemplateRow-" + rowcount;

        // 3. clone the row with our new id
        var $trNew = $trLast.clone(true).prop({ id: newId });

        // 4. rename each input and give an id
        $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {

            oldName = $(this).attr('name');
            inputParts = oldName.split(".");

            // set the  name and id with the base name and rowcount
            $(this).attr('name', '[' + rowcount + '].' + inputParts[1]);
            $(this).attr('id', '[' + rowcount + '].' + inputParts[1]);

            $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");
        });
        $("#[rowcount].Service_Line").change(function () {
            $.get("/Users/GetTrackList", { Service_Line_ID: $("#[rowcount].Service_Line").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#[rowcount].Track").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#[rowcount].Track").append("<option value='" + row.Track_ID + "'>" + row.Track_Options + "</option>")
                });
            });
        })

        $trLast.after($trNew);

        rowcount++;
    });
});
```

The problem is when i try to pull the id's of cloned row from the jquery using $("#[rowcount].Service_Line").change(function () { it's not working can any one please help

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Please clarify the specific problem you're observing.  Which operation in this code is producing an unexpected result?  Are you getting an error?  Something else?

Comment: @David Done....

Comment: I'm afraid you haven't clarified the question.  What specific incrementing value are you trying to read?  Where specifically are you trying to read it?  How have you validated that the value should be there?  Because your code includes server-side code with a dependency on your data, we can't just execute your code to observe what you're seeing.  You need to be specific.

Comment: @David how can i get incrementing id in jquery $("#[rowcount].Service_Line")  the service line is the id of rows having rowcount as increenting value so what i want is like if i have a set of rows with id's like [1].Service_Line,[2].Service_Line,[3].Service_Line,.......then how can i get them in jquery using $ symbol.

Comment: There are a few problems with the line you mention: 1. David has identified the error with the `rowcount`. 2. the format of your id isn't valid (e.g. `[0].Service_Line`) - an id *must* start with a letter so you need to change all your ids to meet this requirement. 3. You are trying to find an element that hasn't fully been added to the DOM, this could cause issues.

Comment: @FluffyKitten How can i solve that issue like u added the id's na with thatnunique id's i need to write jquery so that dropdowns could get populated to each row  from the database

Comment: Please, make your question more clearer. You want to serialize the rows?

Comment: @Borntocode no i want get the id of the cloned rows

Comment: @Borntocode  Can u please help me with dis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63577822/unable-to-populate-dependent-dropdowns-after-cloning-a-row-using-jquery   trying for days but unable to solve the issue i would be very thank ful to u

Comment: You just need to change your ids (and the code that creates them) so they start with a letter. Then make the change David explains below. Then use this in  the line you have problems with, e.g. `$("#Z["+rowcount+"].Service_Line").change(function () {`

Comment: @FluffyKitten Please bro can any one help me with dis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63565686/jquery-after-cloning-the-dependent-dropdowns-are-not-working-for-the-cloned-row?noredirect=1#comment112494263_63565686

Comment: @FluffyKitten It's not fetching the id bro..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how you use the variable `rowcount` in a string here:

```
'[' + rowcount + '].'
```

And notice how you try to use it in a string here:

```
"#[rowcount].Service_Line"
```

See the difference?  In the latter example you're not actually using the `rowcount` variable, you just have a string which contains the literal text `"rowcount"`.  Use the variable just like you did in the former example:

```
"#[" + rowcount + "].Service_Line"
```

(Repeat this for any other places where you want to use a variable in a string.)

You may even be able to use the somewhat newer [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax:

```
`#[${rowcount}].Service_Line`
```

(Note that the syntax highlighting here on Stack Overflow currently doesn't highlight this syntax correctly.)

But in either syntax, the key difference is between using the variable vs. just using a string with the name of the variable.